# I am new to ubuntu.i have installed phpstorm and try to run composer but it's not running

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have installed phpstorm in ubuntu 14.04
Error when i try to acces to database using command php artisan migrate:

```
 wwwsabininfonp@wwwsabininfonp-Aspire-E1-471:/opt/lampp/htdocs/fine-arts$ php artisan migrate                                                                                                             
  [PDOException]                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

and when i tried to use command composer update following error occurs:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - gregwar/captcha dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - gregwar/captcha dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for gregwar/captcha dev-master -> satisfiable by gregwar/captcha[dev-master].
```

I dont know why is this code is scolding me.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says that you need the "gd" extension for PHP. You should be able to install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Comment: It works for composer update, but still the connection problems are present for migration...


Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have installed and configured you MySQL server properly? Is the mysql server running? (you can see that with `sudo service mysql status`)

Comment: its running..
mysql start/running, process 1050